# Do I need a transit visa for my trip from the US to India via Istanbul?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, istanbul

I have an Indian passport with a US work permit. I am traveling back to india via Istanbul. Do I need a transit visa to enter the city for sightseeing? For how long is a transit visa valid?

Comment: #SE is not #Twitter. We do not mark #content with #hashtags.